# Is documentation correct on passing parameters in Blazor to a child component?

Tags: c#, blazor

*This is related to issue: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/31788*

My concern is the Microsoft documentation at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/overwriting-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0

I reproduced this code in repository (link is for "main" page): https://codeberg.org/macias/Demo/src/branch/master/HandlingParameterApp/Pages/ExpanderExample.razor

The original code for child component is this:

```
    private bool expanded;
    
    [Parameter]
    public bool Expanded { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        expanded = Expanded;
    }
```

Which is fine only in very basic scenarios. Let's say I would like to control child from the parent via actions like "expand all". Local member won't be set because the child component is already initialized (it is one time action).

Ok, so I converted this auto property into property with backing field and moved assignment from `OnInitialized` to the setter as the only place when it will be set correctly.

But then somebody would like to have an updates of child state in parent, fine we need another property for callbacks and fire it when the **local** member is changed (so we are acting on behalf on the exposed parameter).

The code ended like this (cleaned up compared to my repo):

```
    private bool expandedLocal;   
    private bool _expandedBackingField;
  
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> ExpandedChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool Expanded
    {
        get => _expandedBackingField;
        set
        {
            if (_expandedBackingField == value)
                return;

            _expandedBackingField = value;
            expandedLocal = Expanded;
        }
    }

    private void Toggle()
    {
        expandedLocal = !expandedLocal;
        ExpandedChanged.InvokeAsync(expandedLocal);
    }
```

Since I started from official documentation my concern/question is this -- is my approach correct or the official one? I am especially worried because the final code is totally convoluted in my opinion (it is more mess than WPF), so maybe I missed something crucial in official version?

*Update: the goal is to follow the guideline described in official documentation, yet make component flexible (parameter could be constant from parent perspective, changeable from parent, or double-way bound) and simple.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respectfully, you are overcomplicating this.  I'm not sure about others, but I did in my early Blazor days.

Parameter properties should look like this.  No exceptions.

```cs
[Parameter] public bool Expanded { get; set; }
```

If you need to get an internal copy or detect a change:

```cs
    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        // Set an internal field or detect a change

        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }
```

Here's my version of your `Expander`.

```cs
<div @onclick="Toggle" class="card bg-light mb-3" style="width:30rem">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">Toggle (<code>expanded</code> = @Expanded)</h2>

         @if (Expanded)
        {
            <p>Expanded</p>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool Expanded { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> ExpandedChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task Toggle()
    {
        await ExpandedChanged.InvokeAsync(!this.Expanded);
    }
}
```

It's a lot simpler.  you don't need to get and hold local copies.  I've removed the ChildContent for a reason I'll explain shortly.

In your code `_expanded1` and `_expanded2` hold the state of the two `Expander` components: the single version of the truth.  You are trying to keep multiple versions of the truth in sync which always becomes a convoluted mess.

Changing their state in the parent is simple.  Set the bool state and call `StateHasChanged`.  If you set the state in a UI event such as a button click, `StateHasChanged` is called for you in the `ComponentBase` UI event handler.  The renderer does a parameter state check for each child component and calls `SetParametersAsync` on any where it detects a possible change.

> I removed the `ChildContent` because it blurs the update/no update decision by the Renderer.  A `RenderFragment` is an object.  The Renderer calls `SetParametersAsync` on all child components with object references: it can't detect a change in state.  Using simple value type parameters means we see if the bool state changes get transmitted to the child components.

If you change the state locally clicking Toggle, you invoke the callback.  This sets the bool state in the parent.  EventCallbacks are treated as UI events in the parent so trigger the `ComponentBase` UI event handler.  This calls `StateHasChanged` on the parent, renders it, and kicks off the parameter check on the child components discussed earlier.

Ask away if you don't understand or want to query anything.

### Update

Based on the need to handle both bind and no bind scenarios I've updated `Expander`.  I've added some commentary to explain the code.

```cs
<div @onclick="Toggle" class="card bg-light mb-3" style="width:30rem">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">Toggle (<code>expanded</code> = @_localExpanded)</h2>

        @if (_localExpanded)
        {
            <p>Expanded</p>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool Expanded { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> ExpandedChanged { get; set; }

    private bool _savedExpanded;  // wheere we store the current state of the parameter Expanded
    private bool _localExpanded;  // The internal state used by the render fragment

    // This is where parameters passed in ParameterView are applied to local Properties
    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        // Always do this first if you are autmatically setting parameters
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        // The Parameter has been updated so we need to save the new state
        // and set the internal state
        if (this.Expanded != _savedExpanded)
        {
            _localExpanded = this.Expanded;
            _savedExpanded = this.Expanded;
        }

        // Call the base to run the standard lifecycle methods
        // We do this with an empty ParameterView as we've already set the parameters
        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }

    private async Task Toggle()
    {
        // If we have a delegate attached then we have binding
        // and Expended will get set from the bind process
        if (ExpandedChanged.HasDelegate)
        {
            await ExpandedChanged.InvokeAsync(!this.Expanded);
            return;
        }

        // No bind, so we're tracking state internallly
        _localExpanded = !_localExpanded;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great idea, I didn't notice I could "get back" from the official doc and make it actually lighter. I will use this approach for sure. But in general sense it is not a solution, please notice I started from the doc to make general/realistic component, as simply as possible yet adhering to the guideline. With your code the component has to know in advance the parent will pass double-way bound variable. In other words it does not work with constants -- and it is a valid use, parent could simply set a sane starting value. I updated the repo with all 3 versions (yours, bad, and mine).

Comment: See my update answer.  I've moved the setter logic into `SetParametersAsync`.  The Parameter getter/setter rule is there for a reason.  You and I may understand where we can break it and understand the consequences of doing so.  Most people reading this question and answer won't.

Comment: I'll have a look at the official document you pointed to.   I've had several changes to the official documents go through recently.  The reason for the very high churn is getting a lot more information on render mode into the documents.  It's proving to be a rather difficult and complex subject for most people to understand.

Comment: Many thanks again. I started from your updated version and trimmed it further. I got rid of saved local copy, and swapped the order of the Toggle. This way the code is much shorter. So in short, the official doc (in my opinion) goes into wrong direction, your approach IMHO is correct one.

Comment: MS had to make some decisions in the early days of Blazor.  In the light of 4+ years of collective experience, some of those decisions were wrong.  Some are now so baked in, it takes a brave or stupid man to defy them, others are just hard to let go of.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is correct.
Based on my experience, it is much better to maintain the expansion state in a separate ExpansionState with NotifyExpansion events and have the Child subscribe to it.
Benefits:

1. The code becomes simpler; no need to track parameters, no "backing fields" etc. Subscribe to the events in OnInitialized and Dispose of the listeners later.
2. You can have much more complex logic around the expansion state (like closing other panes, notification, loading some data)
3. You can reuse the state class (not object instance) for other type of components like drop downs and popups.

Blazor becomes lot simpler if you use MVVM style design.

For example ([github](https://github.com/mayur-ekbote/BlazorCollapse)):

Manage the state here

```
public class CollapseState
{
    public bool IsCollapsed { get; set; } = true;
    public Action<object>? OnToggle {  get; set; }
    public void Collapse(object sender)
    {
        IsCollapsed = true;
        OnToggle?.Invoke(sender);
    }
    public void Exapand(object sender) 
    {
        IsCollapsed = false;
        OnToggle?.Invoke(sender);
    }
    public void Toggle(object sender)
    {
        IsCollapsed = !IsCollapsed;
        OnToggle?.Invoke(sender);
    }
}
```

Then CollapseParent becomes:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-start border border-dark gap-3">
    <div class="d-flex gap-3 pb-2">
        <h3>Collapse Parent</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"  @onclick="ClickButton">Click to Collapse From Parent</button>
    </div>
    <div class="@(collapseState.IsCollapsed ? "text-bg-danger" :"text-bg-success" ) pb-2">
        The Current State of @nameof(CollapseState.IsCollapsed) as seen by the parent is : @collapseState.IsCollapsed
    </div>
    <div class="text-bg-dark">
        Above will *NOT* change if you collapse from the child
    </div>
</div>

<div class="border">
    <CollapseChild CollapseState="@collapseState"></CollapseChild>
</div>



@code {

    CollapseState collapseState;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        collapseState = new CollapseState();
    }
    void ClickButton()
    {
        collapseState.Toggle(this);
    }
}
```

And the child:

```
@if (!CollapseState.IsCollapsed)
{
    <div class="text-success">This is expanded content</div>
    <button class="btn btn-sm" @onclick="@(()=>CollapseState.Toggle(this))">Click to Collapse From Child</button>
}

@code {

    [Parameter]
    [EditorRequired]
    public CollapseState CollapseState { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        CollapseState.OnToggle += OnStateChanged;
    }

    async void OnStateChanged(object sender)
    {
        if (sender != this)
        {
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also make it much more complex. Notify multiple components/ decouple using [MVVM toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/).

Comment: Thank you, but nope, documentation is **not** correct. Please see the marked answer -- official doc leads you to thinking that the right spot for grabbing parameter to local variable is initialization. It is not, parent can change value of the parameter and such scenario is 100% legal. Btw. if you could provide code example it would be really great, because all readers could know for sure what you have in mind, and besides we could compare behaviour side to side with other approaches. Please see the repo.

Comment: The documentation provides an example in which the expander is provided with the *initial* state by the parent and then the child controls its own state for the rest of its life. That is why the toggle button is in the child control. You want dual control - i.e. both the parent and the child should be able to control the state throughout their lifetime. This is the source of confusion!

Comment: There are 3 different child components in the repo. Do let me know which behavior you want to see in the example.

Comment: As for the official doc -- the example of course serve the description, but my point is you cannot go nowhere with this approach. It is dead end. As for the repo, pick whatever you would like as a starting point. The component should work in 3 scenarios -- parameter is fixed in parent (true, false), parameter is not fixed in parent (fold/unfold), and the value is 2-way bound.

Comment: Added a sample. You can play with it to make it more complex.

Comment: Thank you very much, I updated the repo. As for this approach -- I don't think it is convincing :-) Sorry for honesty. It is not possible to simply use it with constant/fixed value. It is more complex than other approaches (it adds another type), also it does not blend in with Blazor well, you have to manually call `StateHasChanged` on child level and even this does not work (parent is not notified about the change, child only). You have to chain event further (up). It is too fragile.